# Hide header when user scrolls to a certain element

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to hide the header of a wordpress site in a nice manner when the user scrolls down. I've got it to work when they scroll 100 pixels down, but its very jumpy, so the user doesn't end up at the top of the section following the header.

My jquery code is this:

```
jQuery(function() {
var header = jQuery(".site-header");
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 100) {
         header.addClass("hidden-header");
    } else {

    }
});
});
```

My CSS is:

```
.site-header{
background-color: #FFF;
transition: all 1s ease;
}

.hidden-header{
visibility: hidden!important;
height: 0!important;
}
```

The above does work, but its clunky. Is there a better way to do this?
The part I'm hiding is a full height image slider, and I don't want it to return, it should stay hidden until the page is reloaded.

Thanks in advance!
Craig

Comment: May be a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I'm not sure if the height will fadeOut correctly.

Here you have an example that maybe matches your needs: https://jsfiddle.net/00Lodcqf/434

```
 jQuery(function() {
    var header = jQuery(".site-header");
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {    
        var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 100) {
             header.fadeOut();
        } else {
             header.fadeIn();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Its doing similar to what I've got already. Mouse wheel scrolling is good, but as soon as you use the scrollbar, it removes the header, but leaves you part way down the next section instead of being at the top of the next section. Thank you for the answer though!